# How can I prevent the webView from being visible till webViewDidFinishLoad is finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm removing content of the webView in the webViewDidFinishLoad. The problem is it first loads the page and shows all the content and then you will see the content I'm removing disappear. I would like it so that the user doesn't see anything disappear so the content should never been shown to the user.

This is my method :

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('menu').style.display='none';"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
    NSLog(@"gets");
}
```

Comment: hide it then unhide it when it finished loading?

Comment: (you learned this in your 3th year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is use of `isLoading` property.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
     if(!webView.isLoading){
          //Has completely stopped..
     }
}
```

Comment: I used a mix of this answer and the answers below adding `webView.hidden = NO;` inside this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use webview.hidden = YES till the time you dont want to see the data and then set it as no again

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIWebView Delegate` methods as shown below.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
  webView.hidden = YES;

    return YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

    webView.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the same thing work in `viewDidLoad` ?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

       NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('menu').style.display='none';"];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
        NSLog(@"gets");
}
```